# Digital dice counting from 1 to 6

Tags: digital-logic

[image: corrected picture of the electronic dice] check it out guys [image] ][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Xp5u.jpg)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Xp5u.jpg)  the circuits above are both for an electronic dice that is supposed to count from 1 to 6 but none of the LEDS are turning on for the one that is far below, can anyone tell me what I did wrong and the top most one LEDS D9 and D10 aren't coming on as well. Can anyone tell me why and please bear with the quality of the picture and the quality of my english.

[image]

Comment: You have VDD tied to ground near the middle top.

Comment: must ... get ... focus ...

Comment: You have used some software to design and print these circuits, right? Why not post the schematics without the "printer-camera-in-the-middle" thing?

Comment: Maybe you could make a screen-shot on the computer and upload it from there.

Comment: ok i dont really know how to screenshot in proteus

Comment: Could you show the LEDs as diodes, please, not as round blobs.  The arrow in the LED symbol must point towards ground.

Comment: Alt+PrintScreen? But a better way would be to export it to an image format if possible

Comment: Are you on windows? If so, search for [Snipping Tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/snipping-tool) in the Start Menu, the rest is up to you.

Comment: @BenceKaulics Well, today I've learn something new :)

Comment: okay i will thanks everyone i upload a better quality as soon as possible cheers

Comment: D9 and D10 in the first schematic are shorted by the ground wire from D17 and D15.

Comment: Do you really have to use the discrete logic parts? You have so many components to worry about. Why not use Arduino Pro Mini or some PIC micro? You'd need just resistors for the LEDs. Controlling all the LEDs and the button would be done in software. It'd be so cool if the numbers started changing fast when the button is pressed and keep slowing down until the number is selected...

Comment: @Alex MUCH learning can and will be done using discrete parts. Magic software mumbling can follow.

Comment: @Alex: While it's all well and good to espouse the use of programmable hardware, note that the querent provided concrete circuit details in the form of schematics, while you provide no code to back up your position, but only the ever more irresponsible catchall: "Use a PIC". Please don't misunderstand me; my intent isn't to be pejorative or combative,  but rather just to point out that if you have a software solution it would help if you'd post the code instead of just the mantra.

Comment: Re your third photo: It is common in most CAD systems to hide Vcc and GND (or Vss/Vdd) pins, to avoid cluttering the schematic with power and ground connections.  Such hidden pins are automagically connected to other pins of the same name, and to nets of the same name.

Comment: @Russell McMahon Right. You could even build an AVR micro using TTL chips and then program it. You would learn a ton from that. Oh man, it's so 1970s...

Comment: @EM Fields. The piece of code in C to do that would be really trivial. That was only a suggestion. If I really wanted to be pugnacious I would say "why waste your time, buy a $10 electronic dice kit from China"...

Comment: @Alex I was apalled at your last answer ! :-) - BUT I looked at your other answers and see elsewhere you reminiscing re 749x and good old days. (Thyat makes you not quite as old as me :-) ). The point is, hands on ICs and logic **IS** a painful and slow way to do things, but will teach lessons re gate functions and power supply levels and loadings and time constants and more. Start like that and mastery (as opposed to blind copying) of typical modern circuits gets much easier. (I predate the OC70 :-) ).

Comment: I hear you. It's possible that playing with the 74 family ICs myself back in the day got me where I'm at right now. You never know... :D (hmmm OC70 is a Germanium transistor? I heard about these...)

Comment: In the third impossibly blurry picture, it looks like you have an input of U4A connected to some blurry BJT maybe....